# Query several fields containing a list of string values (Realm Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to query several fields at the same time containing a list of string value in Realm. Let say I have the following Object:

```
class Book: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var category = ""
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var story = ""
}
```

To search one keyword in multiple fields, I use the following code:

```
let predicateKeyword = NSPredicate(format: "category CONTAINS[c] %@ OR title CONTAINS[c] %@ OR story CONTAINS[c] %@", keyword, keyword, keyword)
```

To search multiple keywords in one fields, I use the following code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "story CONTAINS[c] %@", argumentArray: specialKeywords)
```

What if I have multiple keywords to query in multiple fields at the same time. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can using IN 
The containment operand IN, e.g. name IN {'Lisa', 'Spike', 'Hachi'}

see document . https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate) against hand crafting predicate strings. With an NSCompoundPredicate you can potentially string together multiple or or as a.masri rightly calls out, in predicates to form a single predicate that you can then pass to realm.